# PartiQL DynamoDB IN statement implementation

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, partiql

I am wondering about the underlying PartiQL implementation of the `SELECT ... WHERE PrimaryKey IN` statement with respect to its performance in DynamoDB.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE PK IN [1, 2, 3]
```

Given that the lower-level Query API - Key condition expressions for query does not support `IN` statement, only `=` on key condition ([source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.KeyConditionExpressions)). Does this mean that this will result in 3 queries to DynamoDB or is it a single one ?

Or is this implemented using a [filter expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html#Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.Syntax) on the results under the hood , which supports `IN`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It still sends a single request to DynamoDB. But when the request hits the backend, it's executed in 3 Query calls sequentially. So it's useful for simplicity but not as performant as executing 3 individual Query calls async.

Comment: Thanks you for the clear answer, appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome Lucian, feel free to accept the answer if it satisfies your question.

Comment: Done. Just to be clear, recommendation on performance on this usecase would actually be to try 3 parallel async calls using the Query API , correct ?

Comment: Yea, as with PartiQL they would be done synchronously on the backend. Where if you can achieve it asynchronously then you will have better performance.